# Can't get Textillate to work - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: jquery, animation, plugins, jquery-plugins

Hi guys I've been fiddling around with the textillate plugin but I simply can't get it to work. I'm overlooking something.

I started a new document and followed the instructions to make a demo.

jQuery itself seems to be working fine. I hid the element to test if the library was working through my.js file.

I have all the files physically in the root folder. For the purpose of the demo I have no additional folders included so the location of the files should be correct.

I tried Chrome and Safari.

Here's my markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.css">
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.lettering.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.textillate.js"></script>
 <script src="my.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <h1 class="tlt">Nathan</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And the JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".tlt").textillate();
});
```

this should trigger the default animation, right?